# a number of vendors is/are?

Tags: grammatical-number

I think "a number of vendors **are**" is the right way, but "MS Word Grammar Check" suggested "a number of vendors **is**".
I need a clarification on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of your sentence is **vendors**. As it is plural, it takes a plural verb as well. So "are" is correct.

Comment: 'A number of' [X's] is a compound (three-word) quantifier triggering plural verb agreement.

Comment: You're right. But if we cross out "a number of", still the subject takes a plural verb, doesn't it?

Comment: But if you cross out 'A team of' from 'A team of huskies needs a driver with a very strong personality', it can be seen that your 'test' fails. One needs to look at compound quantifiers, and collective nouns, individually.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks, Edwin. +1 for being perfect at explaining tricky stuff.

Comment: I'm good at explaining how stuff _doesn't_ work.

Comment: "Any fool can make something complicated. It takes a genius to make it simple." :-) Woody Guthrie