# Counting nouns using "slew" and the grammatical implications

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, collective-nouns

Just having a lively debate with a content writer over whether we should say

> There are a slew of reasons...

or

> There is a slew of reasons...

Read [this article](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/plurals.htm) which suggests that different words are treated differently in this situation, so I'm wondering if *slew* would behave more like *number*, as in, *There are a number of reasons*, or if it would be more like *group*, as in *There is a group of people that believe...*.

Any thoughts on how one can decide for a word like *slew*?

Possible duplicate of:
[a number of vendors is/are?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174936/a-number-of-vendors-is-are)
[Is the sentence "There is a large number of labourers who want to migrate to Japan for work." correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51729/is-the-sentence-there-is-a-large-number-of-labourers-who-want-to-migrate-to-jap)

Answer (score 3):

*slew* is defined at [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slew) as

> A large number or quantity of something.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slew)

> a large number

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/slew)

> a large number or quantity

So it's a number, not a group, and therefore gets the plural verb "there are".